# Set variable in class from another class

Tags: swift

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class ContactsHolder {
    static let name = "joe"
}
```

and from another class I can call it like so:

```
println(ContactsHolder.name)
```

My question is how do I set that variable to something else?

I tried:

`ContactsHolder.name = "bob"` and get `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`

Am I going about this completely wrong or what do I need to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `let` you declare a constant that can't be modified.

You can use a variable instead:

```
class ContactsHolder {
    static var name = "joe"
}

ContactsHolder.name = "mike"

println(ContactsHolder.name) // prints "mike"
```

Comment: ok this works, I also just found out that I could set name in a swift file and access from anywhere without even referencing the swift file name. Are there disadvantages of making my ContactsHolder.swift file not have a class and just have `var name = "joe"` in it and from my view controller do this: `name = "bob"       println(name)`

Comment: Indeed this is not ideal because then your content isn't separated from anything else. It's bad practice to "pollute" the global scope with variables. :) Better "encapsulate" within classes, structs, enums, etc.

Comment: @BluGeni This answer is correct, but should probably be edited to state that this isn't how you should handle variables, for newbies to programming. Making static variables can be bad practice if you don't know what you're doing. Think of variables like 'properties' of real world objects. A book has a numPages, a coverColor etc. Read up on object oriented programming before going ahead any further.

Comment: @Chackle I agree that static variables should be handled with care. But it was OP's specific question, so I tried to answer it in the most simple way. I think I should not edit it. Someone else can add another answer with other kind of data structures as examples if they want.